# How do I get when a review was requested on a Github PR

Tags: github, github-api

I need a way to get when a reviewer for a GitHub PR was requested using their API, but looking through the documentation there seems to be no way to do it. Is there any way that I can get the information I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when a pull request review was requested, [you can set up a webhook for the `pull_request` event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request).  Then, you can listen for the `review_requested` and `review_request_removed` actions and do whatever you'd like in response.

Note that with GitHub webhooks, you will get all of the messages for a particular event, and you're responsible for filtering out the ones you want.  GitHub doesn't provide filtering capabilities.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for that info, it isn't applicable to what I was doing but I have found out that it is actually impossible without a webhook.

Comment: The GitHub API doesn't support polling operations, so yeah, you'll need a webhook if you want to be notified when something happens.